# How to scroll another buffer while in minibuffer?

Tags: elisp, window

I'll describe what I'm doing currently to get an issue. First, I store the current buffer.

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `eval-expression`

```cl
(setq bb (current-buffer))
```

Then, <kbd>M-:</kbd>

```cl
(with-current-buffer bb
  (insert "foo"))
```

While still in minibuffer, <kbd>C-e</kbd>, <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>. I get the expected result: `foo`
is inserted in the buffer `bb`.

However, if I change the expression to

```cl
(with-current-buffer bb
  (goto-char (point-min)))
```

After <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> I get the result `1`, but the point doesn't move.
It would seem that scrolling is disabled while in minibuffer. How can I enable it?

Comment: Interesting problem. What's more interesting is that if you eval `(with-current-buffer (other-buffer) (goto-char (point-max)))` with `C-x C-e` then the point will move.

Comment: @nanny, doesn't work on 24.4.91

Comment: I just double- and triple-checked, it definitely works for me on 24.4.1 (Cygwin). Process: run `emacs -Q`, open two files, hit `M-:`, type the elisp in my above comment (alternating `point-min` and `point-max`), hit `C-x C-e`, then quit eval with `C-g`, and the point is at the other side of `other-buffer`.

Comment: It might be a version issue. Although I want the scroll to happen *before* `C-g`.

Comment: I think this is happening because you're changing the point during recursive edit. I'm not sure how to avoid it. Try messing with window-point.

Comment: You're right! `(setf (window-point wnd) (point))` worked. But why?

Comment: `w-c-b` does not change the selected window ? I've never fully comprehended how `point` and `window-point` relate. E.g. when edebugging and displaying the buffer where text is inserted it would sometimes move point and sometimes not.

Comment: `w-c-b` changes the window, but does not scroll. Very strange.

Comment: But `(with-current-buffer (other-buffer) (eq (window-buffer (selected-window)) (current-buffer)))` returns nil.

Comment: @abo-abo does this general issue happen if you try to scroll another window without being in the minibuffer? (i.e., just split a second window and execute the snippet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved by using `with-selected-window` instead of `with-current-buffer`.
I thought that they would be equivalent in this case, but they're not.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is happening because you're changing the point during recursive edit. I'm not sure how to avoid this situation in general, but here, instead of `goto-char` you can set `window-point`:

```
(setf (window-point (get-buffer-window bb)) (point-min))
```

Comment: I'm in `read-from-minibuffer`, trying to scroll the window from `post-command-hook`. While `window-point` can be updated, `window-start` and `window-end` still won't re-compute.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably after this info:   [(elisp) Window Point](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Point.html)

> Each window has its own value of point (*note Point::), independent of
>   the value of point in other windows displaying the same buffer.  This
>   makes it useful to have multiple windows showing one buffer.
>
> ...
>
> - As long as the selected window displays the current buffer, the
>       window's point and the buffer's point always move together; they
>       remain equal.